# Is it true that oral sex exists in non-human animals?

Tags: zoology

For example, outside of humans, do other species of animals engage in oral sex, or any oral stimulation of others' genitals purely for pleasure, not any cleansing habits, etc.?

Basically, what I am saying is, is it true that oral sex, like in humans, exists in non-human animals?

Comment: Then of course you have the sexual deviants like [this chimp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVE60zwXx1k).

Comment: I am not going to sugar coat this or lie folks....this is graphic.
Elephants:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q12ApVIjkD0 Then again, that is the snout so that's technically not oral...food for thought I guess... https://books.google.com/books?id=tmFJ1LhbVWcC&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=elephants+oral+sex&source=bl&ots=RYPwHuK4VA&sig=I37vEU8-GlSuE5TAVdYaOeT-C5M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8sgpVdi6GcKdgwSUpYHYBg&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=elephants%20oral%20sex&f=false

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is true. Have a look at this post:[9 Animals Who Are Into Oral Sex](http://www.thefrisky.com/2013-04-04/9-animals-who-are-into-oral-sex/):

> A recent study of fruit bats found cunnilingus to be a major part of their repertoire. While following a colony of 420 bats roosting in a fig tree over the course of 13 months, researchers witnessed 57 incidences of sex — both oral and intercourse. The female bats who received oral sex before intercourse were found to last longer during copulation.

The paper they cite is [this one](http://www.plosone.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0059743).

[image]